# Add prefix and suffix to Collectors.joining() only if there are multiple items present

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of strings:

```
Stream<String> stream = ...;
```

I want to construct a string which concatenates these items with `,` as a separator. I do this as following:

```
stream.collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Now I want add a prefix `[` and a suffix `]` to this output only if there were multiple items. For example:

- `a`
- `[a,b]`
- `[a,b,c]`

Can this be done without first materializing the `Stream<String>` to a `List<String>` and then checking on `List.size() == 1`? In code:

```
public String format(Stream<String> stream) {
    List<String> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (list.size() == 1) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return "[" + list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]";
}
```

It feels odd to first convert the stream to a list and then again to a stream to be able to apply the `Collectors.joining(",")`. I think it's suboptimal to loop through the whole stream (which is done during a `Collectors.toList()`) only to discover if there is one or more item(s) present.

I could implement my own `Collector<String, String>` which counts the number of given items and use that count afterwards. But I am wondering if there is a directer way.

This question intentionally ignores there case when the stream is empty.

Comment: "construct a string" or rather "construct a stream" ?

Comment: The Streams have the count() method that gives the number of elements in the list, that way you don't have to materialize the stream, rather use it instead of list.size()

Comment: @AmanJ  `count()` is a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). After that the `stream` cannot be used anymore, it's consumed.

Comment: There is no more direct way than making your own collector.

Comment: it's a bit out of scope of your question but you can refactor last line of your code:
stream.collect(Collectors.joining("-", "[", "]")); =))

Comment: Your code is wrong, you can't collect a stream twice. You should stream the list and then collect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using a custom `Collector` instance that will use an anonymous object with a count of items in the stream and an overloaded `toString()` method:

```
public String format(Stream<String> stream) {
    return stream.collect(
            () -> new Object() {
                StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
                int count;

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return count == 1 ? stringJoiner.toString() : "[" + stringJoiner + "]";
                }
            },
            (container, currentString) -> {
                container.stringJoiner.add(currentString);
                container.count++;
            },
            (accumulatingContainer, currentContainer) -> {
                accumulatingContainer.stringJoiner.merge(currentContainer.stringJoiner);
                accumulatingContainer.count += currentContainer.count;
            }
                         ).toString();
}
```

---

## Explanation

[`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) interface has the following methods:

```
public interface Collector<T,A,R> {
    Supplier<A> supplier();
    BiConsumer<A,T> accumulator();
    BinaryOperator<A> combiner();
    Function<A,R> finisher();
    Set<Characteristics> characteristics();
}
```

I will omit the last method as it is not relevant for this example.

There is a `collect()` method with the following signature:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

and in our case it would resolve to:

```
<Object> Object collect(Supplier<Object> supplier,
              BiConsumer<Object, ? super String> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<Object, Object> combiner);
```

- In the `supplier`, we are using an instance of `StringJoiner` (basically the same thing that `Collectors.joining()` is using).
- In the `accumulator`, we are using `StringJoiner::add()` but we increment the count as well
- In the `combiner`, we are using `StringJoiner::merge()` and add the count to the accumulator
- Before returning from `format()` function, we need to call `toString()` method to wrap our accumulated `StringJoiner` instance in `[]` (or leave it as is is, in case of a single-element stream

The case for an empty case could also be added, I left it out in order not to make this collector more complicated.

Comment: The same can be achieved using `Stream.reduce(...)` where the `identity` is `new Object() { ... }` and the `accumulator ` does `return container;` and then `combiner` does `return accumulatingContainer;` But is's longer than your solution, so your solution is still preferable.

Comment: @LuCio …and it would be broken by definition, as `reduce` does not work with mutable containers. That’s precisely what `collect` is for.

Comment: @Holger: You're right. The task from the question needs a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReductionl). And the documentation says: _The mutable reduction operation is called `collect()`, as it collects together the desired results into a result container_. My approach misuses the ordinary [reduction operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) since the `accumulator` wraps a container. - Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

There is already an accepted answer and I upvoted it too.

Still I would like to offer potentially another solution. Potentially because it has one requirement:
The `stream.spliterator()` of `Stream<String> stream` needs to be `Spliterator.SIZED`.

If that applies to your case, you could use also this solution:

```
  public String format(Stream<String> stream) {
    Spliterator<String> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
    StringJoiner sj = spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 1 ?
      new StringJoiner("") :
      new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
    spliterator.forEachRemaining(sj::add);

    return sj.toString();
  }
```

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getExactSizeIfKnown()) `Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown()` "returns `estimateSize()` if this `Spliterator` is `SIZED`, else `-1`." If a `Spliterator` is [`SIZED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#SIZED) then "`estimateSize()` prior to traversal or splitting represents a finite size that, in the absence of structural source modification, represents an exact count of the number of elements that would be encountered by a complete traversal."

Since "most Spliterators for Collections, that cover all elements of a `Collection` report this characteristic" (API Note in JavaDoc of `SIZED`) this could be the desired *directer way*.

**EDIT:**
If the `Stream` is empty we can return an empty `String` at once. If the `Stream` has only one `String` there is no need to create a `StringJoiner` and to copy the `String` to it. We return the single `String` directly.

```
  public String format(Stream<String> stream) {
    Spliterator<String> spliterator = stream.spliterator();

    if (spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    if (spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown() == 1) {
      AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<String>();
      spliterator.tryAdvance(result::set);
      return result.get();
    }

    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
    spliterator.forEachRemaining(result::add);
    return result.toString();
  }
```

Comment: If you know that the Stream has a single `String` element, you could return that single element directly, omitting the copying to a `StringJoiner` and to a new `String`. But you should also handle the case where a stream has no known size but ends up having one element. It’s not a weird corner case, i.e. `Stream.of("foo").filter(s -> true)` does already fit into that category.

Answer (score -1):

I know that I'm late to the party, but I too came across this very same problem recently, and I thought it might be worthwhile documenting how I solved it.

While the accepted solution does work, my opinion is that it is more complicated than it needs to be, making it both hard to read and understand. As opposed to defining an `Object` implementation and then separate accumulator and combiner functions that access and modify the state of said object, why not just define your own collector? In the problem presented above, this can be achieved as follows:

```java
Collector<CharSequence, StringJoiner, String> collector = new Collector<>() {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public Supplier<StringJoiner> supplier() {
        return () -> new StringJoiner(",");
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<StringJoiner, CharSequence> accumulator() {
        return (joiner, sequence) -> {
            count++;
            joiner.add(sequence);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<StringJoiner> combiner() {
        return StringJoiner::merge;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<StringJoiner, String> finisher() {
        return (joiner) -> {
            String joined = joiner.toString();
            return (count > 1) ? "[" + joined + "]" : joined;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
};
```

The principle is the same, you have a counter that is incremented whenever elements are added to the `StringJoiner`. Based on the total number of elements added, the `finisher` decides wheater the `StringJoiner` result should be wrapped in square brackets. It goes without saying, but you can even define a separate class specific to this implementation, allowing it to be used throughout your codebase. You can even go a step further by making it more generic to support a wider range of input types, adding custom prefix/suffix parameters, and so on. Speaking of use, just pass instances of the collector to the `collect` method of your `Stream`:

```java
return list.stream().collect(collector);
```

Comment: The OP reject the ` "[" + joined + "]"  `  in the question as it is suboptimal.
I will reject your proposal also because it's less readable than doing ` "[" + list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]"; `.

But the main point here is that you break the stream logic which the accepted answer doesn't. Other issues come from that break.

Comment: Hi @blobmaster, I'm wondering what you mean by "break the stream logic". My answer is based on the accepted answer and contains almost identical code. IMO a separate class definition is more readable than defining a custom implementation of a `new Object`. Also, what "other issues" are present in the code?

Comment: Hi @Orzen. by creating the "joined" Sting you are dumping all the data of the stream in memory but it's what OP asked. And you're right I missed the join in the accepted answer, sorry for that. Others == readability and optimization. There is no optimization in accepted answer and yours, just more code and a behavior that looks hidden inside some anonymous technical.
It's a mater of taste + you may want to encapsulate a behavior in a well named collector.
`list.size() == 1 ? list.get(0): "[" + list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]"; ` looks more readable to me.